# Can't fix row borders using css in DataTables

Tags: css, datatables

I'm trying to add a darker border to the bottom of specific rows in my table.

I've added a custom class to the rows (`des-rec-row`) and have included the following in my CSS:

```
.des-rec-row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}
```

In Chrome's dev tools, the class and css property is showing as active, but the border isn't correct. I can hover over the property and see where the border *should* be.

I've also reproduced this in https://jsfiddle.net/onLuw2pa/. If you add `border-bottom: 1px solid black` in the dev tools to any of the rows, nothing happens.

Is this a specificity issue? Is it inheritance? Is there overlap happening? I'll admit CSS isn't my specialty, can someone help me solve this?

EDIT----

Updated jsFiddle with ineffective CSS:
https://jsfiddle.net/n3o78yL1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant add border to `tr`, However you can add it to each `td` inside it and it'll look the same.

Edit Your css and make it:

```
.even td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c50tj8fr/